# XML Highliting Error from Android Lint

Tags: android, xml, devops, lint

Hello Guys I have a project Module which consist of some Layout and code. 
the problem is that i got error from lint

> XML Attribute is not allowed it here

for example `android_width` cause lint knows the folder is not in `"app/res/layout"` folder. Instead it is inside `"my-lib/res/layout"` folder
My question is :- how can i solve this problem to make understand lint, so i will not get error.
thanks!

[image]

Comment: can you send your Error Here?? And Some Code of your my-lib Which Gives Error.

Comment: post your manifest file.

Comment: @DropAndTrap in your manifest file if version Code And version name are added then remove it , add inside application tag in manifest  android:allowBackup="true". then , save ,close and reopen project

Answer (score 1):

You can try to specify layout folder manually in `gradle` file

```
sourceSets {
  main {
      res.srcDirs =
      [
            'path-to-my-lib/res/layout'
      ]
    }
}
```

Comment: i need to specify about lint path r u sure about the problem?